# Trying to post data via html-form and JavaScript to RESTapi – gets 404 Cannot Post?

Tags: forms, post, http-status-code-404, http-method

I have googled a lot, gone through a lot of questions but can't find an answer.
I have built a simple RESTapi with node and mongoDB, using express and mongoose. The database is hosted on Atlas. The RESTapi works fine when accessing with postman, no problem there.

To access and use the RESTapi via the site I get the GET and DELETE method to work, but when trying to post data with a form I get the error “Cannot Post/ 404”. I have tried a lot of things but can´t get it to work. (I don't know it it is related, but the content-security policies which makes some scripts don't load, I have tried to allow everything in the head meta-info in index.html, but it doesn't make a change)
[image: error shown in web dev tool]

Request headers

```
Accept
    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control
    no-cache
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Length
    530
Content-Type
    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------52045656921129358052645853016
Host
    localhost:3000
Origin
    http://localhost:3000
Pragma
    no-cache
Referer
    http://localhost:3000/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
    1
```

The RESTapi and the site accessing is in the same folder, here is the project structure:

[image: structure of project]

Here is the code:
js/main.js

```js
window.onload = loadCourses();
// Variebles from the form
let formCreate = document.getElementById("formCreate");
let courseIdIn = document.getElementById("courseId");
let courseNameIn = document.getElementById("courseName");
let coursePeriodIn = document.getElementById("coursePeriod");
let message_form = document.getElementById("message_form");

const myForm = document.getElementById('formCreate');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    console.log('Hello from eventlistner');
    e.preventDefault();
    addCourse();
})

// GET courses
function loadCourses() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/courses", function(data) {
        //rensa listan
        console.log(data);
        $("#tbody").html("");
        for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
            $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + data[i]._id + "</td>" + "<td>"+ data[i].courseId + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].courseName + 
"</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].coursePeriod + "</td>" + "<td><img class='deleteSize' onclick='deleteCourse(\""+data[i]._id+"\")' src='images/delete-photo.svg'alt='ikon radare'></td></tr>");
        }
    });
}

// DELETE course
function deleteCourse(id) {
    console.log(id)
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/courses/" + id
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        
        //ladda om listan
        loadCourses();
    });
}

// add course
function addCourse() {
    console.log("Hi from add Course");
    let courseIdEl = courseIdIn .value;
    let courseNameEl = courseNameIn.value;
    let coursePeriodEl = coursePeriodIn.value;

    let courseObj = 
    {
        "courseId": courseIdEl.value,
        "courseName": courseNameEl.value,
        "coursePeriod": coursePeriodEl.value
    }
    console.log(courseObj);
    //Skapar fetch-anrop
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/courses', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': '*/*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(courseObj)
    })

    .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // message
            let message = data.message;
            message_form.innerHTML = message;
            //document.getElementById("message_form").innerHTML = message;
            loadCourses();
            formCreate.reset();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        })
}
```

the index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-policy" content="default-src *; 
script-src *;
connect-src *;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="main2.js"></script>
    <title>Moment 3 - mongoose.js</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Moment 3 - mongoose.js</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Kurs</th>
                <th>Kursnamn</th>
                <th>Period</th>
                <th>Radera</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>DT162G</td>
                <td>JavaScript-basar webbutveckling</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><img class="deleteSize" onclick="deleteCourse()" src="images/delete-photo.svg" alt="ikon radare">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h3>Create course:</h3>
    <form class="forms" action="" id="formCreate" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!--fält för formulär, hela den grå delen-->
        <fieldset id="field">
            <p class="pfield" id="message_form"></p>
            <label for="courseId">Kurskod:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="courseId" id="courseId" class="input">
            <br>
            <label for="courseName">Kursnamn:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="courseName" id="courseName" class="input">
            <br>
            <label for="coursePeriod">Kursperiod:</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="coursePeriod" name="coursePeriod" min="1" max="2">
            <div class="btn-wrapper">
                <button type="submit" name="submitPost" id="btn-create" class="btn btn2">Publish</button>
                <button type="reset" name="deletePost" id="btn-reset" class="btn btn2 btn-reset">Delete
                    field</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**RESTapi code**

routes/courses.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router =  express.Router();

// Hämtar schemamodel
const Courses = require('../models/CourseModel');



// Get all courses
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allCourses = await Courses.find();
        if(!allCourses) {
            throw Error('No items found');
        } else  {
            res.status(200).json(allCourses);
        }

    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json( {msg: err})
    }
})
// GET one course
router.get('/:id', getCourse, (req, res) => {
    res.json(res.course)
})

// Create course
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const newCourse = new Courses({
        courseName: req.body.courseName,
        courseId: req.body.courseId,
        coursePeriod: req.body.coursePeriod
    });

    try {
        const course = await newCourse.save();
        if(!course) {
            throw Error('Something went wrong while saving the post =( ');
        } else {
            // It worked ok, post is created
            res.status(201).json(course);
        }
            
    } catch (err) {
        // bad input from user = 400
        res.status(400).json( {msg: err})
    }
});

// UPDATE one course
router.patch('/:id', getCourse, async (req, res) => {
    // options new = true makes mangoose send back updated data and not old
    let options = { new: true }; 
    try {
        const course = await Courses.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, options);
        if(!course) {
            throw Error ('Something went wrong while updating the post =( ');
        } else {
             // It worked ok, post is created
             res.json(course).status(201).json( {success: true});
            }
    } catch {
        res.status(400).json( {message: err.message})
    }
})

// DELETE one course
router.delete('/:id', getCourse, async (req, res) => {
   try {
        await res.course.deleteOne();
        res.status(200).json( {message: 'Success: Course is deleted!'})
   } catch (err){
        res.status(503).json( {message: err.message})
   }
})



// Creating middlewhere function to re-use, findbyid. Middlewhere idé = webdev simplified
async function getCourse(req, res, next) {
    let course;
    try {
        course = await Courses.findById(req.params.id)
        if (course == null) {
            return res.status(404).json( {message: 'Cant find any course with that ID'})
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json( {message: err.message})
    }

    res.course = course;
    next();
}

module.exports = router;
```

models/CourseModel.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CourseSchema = new Schema( {
    courseName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    courseId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    coursePeriod: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Courses', CourseSchema );
```

server.js

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//const { MONGO_URI } = require('./config');

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false  })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to Mongo Database.'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));


//BodyParser Middleware, for use of JSON in body 
app.use(express.json());

// skapa statisk sökväg
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Routes
const courseRoutes = require('./routes/courses.js')
app.use('/courses', courseRoutes)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log (`Server run at port ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

well, it was a stupid mistake in HTML, the script source tag for the javascript-file main.js was in the head section. Of course, it must be in the bottom just before the body-tag. So stupid of me.